# DBT workflow on Databricks fails: AttributeError in object SeedNode

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, dbt

Today our DBT workflow in databricks failed. The workflow runs as:

```
dbt run --target workflow --project-dir dbt/projectdir/ --profiles-dir dbt/
```

Any suggestions what could be wrong or how to fix it?

**Version reported in Databricks logs:**

> Running with dbt=1.4.1

**The error message below:**

> 'SeedNode' object has no attribute 'depends_on'
>
> 09:59:17  Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 135, in main
> results, succeeded = handle_and_check(args)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 198, in handle_and_check
> task, res = run_from_args(parsed)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 245, in run_from_args
> results = task.run()
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/task/runnable.py", line 454, in run
> self._runtime_initialize()
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/task/runnable.py", line 165, in _runtime_initialize
> super()._runtime_initialize()
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/task/runnable.py", line 94, in _runtime_initialize
> self.load_manifest()
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/task/runnable.py", line 81, in load_manifest
> self.manifest = ManifestLoader.get_full_manifest(self.config)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/parser/manifest.py", line 203, in get_full_manifest
> manifest = loader.load()
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/parser/manifest.py", line 339, in load
> self.parse_project(
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/parser/manifest.py", line 467, in parse_project
> parser.parse_file(block)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/parser/base.py", line 425, in parse_file
> self.parse_node(file_block)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/parser/base.py", line 386, in parse_node
> self.render_update(node, config)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/parser/base.py", line 363, in render_update
> self.update_parsed_node_config(node, config, context=context)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/parser/base.py", line 336, in update_parsed_node_config
> get_rendered(hook.sql, context, parsed_node, capture_macros=True)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 590, in get_rendered
> return render_template(template, ctx, node)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 545, in render_template
> return template.render(ctx)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render
> self.environment.handle_exception()
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
> raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
> File "", line 1, in top-level template code
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/sandbox.py", line 393, in call
> return __context.call(__obj, *args, **kwargs)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 328, in **call**
> with self.track_call():
> File "/usr/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 117, in **enter**
> return next(self.gen)
> File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 319, in track_call
> self.node.depends_on.add_macro(unique_id)
>
> AttributeError: 'SeedNode' object has no attribute 'depends_on'

Answer (score 0):

Seems this was a version issue. Explicitly setting the task to use an older version seems to have solved it:

```
dbt-core<=1.3.1
dbt-databricks<=1.3.1
```

This can be set in the Databricks workflow task settings.

I'm not sure which is the last version that would work, but 1.3.1 at least works in our case.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue but I am on snowflake

Comment: This does not at all answer the question, it is better to write this as a comment on the question or the other answer